# Issue to build mupdf library for android

Tags: android, pdf, compiler-errors, mupdf

I follow [this](http://mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android) to build mupdf library.

But I got the following error message at step 3: make generate

> LINK build/debug/cmapdump ld: library not found for -lX11 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) make: *** [build/debug/cmapdump] Error 1

I found a few questions about the mupdf compilation in stack overflow. But I could not find any one similar to my problem.

By the way, my environment is:

1. Mac 10.8.3
2. NDK r8e
3. mupdf 1.2

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an oversight in the makefiles. Until it is fixed, run the generate step like this:

```
make generate NOX11=yes
```

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the 1.2.zip file and recompile it, everything went well too.